# Translate native sql to JPA code or JPQL and make it pageable and sortable

Tags: java, jpa, spring-data-jpa, jpql

I have two Entities like Below:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="tb_sm_config")
class Config {
   @Id
   private Long id;
   private String code;
   private String name;
   @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
   private State state;
   @JsonIgnore
   @OneToMany(mappedBy = "config", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
   private List<ConfigItem> items;
}

@Entity
@Table(name="tb_sm_config_item")
class ConfigItem {
   @Id
   private Long id;
   private String code;
   private String name;
   @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
   private State state;
   @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
   @JoinColumn(name = "config_id", referencedColumnName = "id", foreignKey = @ForeignKey(ConstraintMode.NO_CONSTRAINT))
    private Config config;
}
```

the State is an Enum, there are three states : VALID, INVALID, DELETED

Then I define a ConfigVO like below:

```
class ConfigVO {
   private Long id;
   private String code;
   private String name;
   private State state;
   private Long validItemCount;
   private Long invalidItemCount;
   pirvate Long deletedItemCount;
}
```

I want to provide fuzzy query based on config.name, config.code and precise query based on config.state and return a list of ConfigVO with pageable and sortable.

I know native sql will like :

```
select a.id, a.code, a.name, a.state,
       coalesce(b._valid, 0) validItemCount,
       coalesce(b._invalid, 0) invalidItemCount,
       coalesce(b._deleted, 0) deletedItemCount
from tb_sm_config a left join
    (select config_id, sum(if(state = 'VALID', 1, 0)) _valid, sum(if(state = 'INVALID', 1, 0)) _invalid, sum(if(state = 'DELETED', 1, 0)) _deleted  from tb_sm_config_item group by config_id) b
on a.id = b.config_id
where code like %:code% and name like %:name% and state = :state
```

But here are the problems I don't know how to deal with:

1. The frontend will not always pass the code, name, state to query, so these three parameters is nullable.
2. If I use the @Query(nativeQuery=true, value=xxxx) in the ConfigRepository interface method, I don't know how to deal with the null value and the paging and sorting.

Is that any possible to achieve this goal through JpaSpecificationExecutor interface, Example interface, or something else?

I want to query base on the code, name, state, sometimes they will be null and want to count the total number of individual configItem states and pageable and sortable.

Comment: https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-criteria-queries

Comment: the baeldung tutorial is helpful but my ConfigVO is not an Entity, it contains some fields that need to be calculated. So the tutorial is not perfect match

Comment: Sure but there is never a perfect match for a problem in development. You should first try to solve the problem yourself. And then ask question what is not working for you https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask